# Marker doesn't show in maps api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Why does my marker not appear?
I also tried without the line "marker.show", but the marker just seems not to appear.

```
<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Custom Control</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ZoomPanControl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {  
    var myOptions = {  
        zoom: 10,  
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.3732589, 8.2382168),  
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,  
        navigationControl: true }  
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);  
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: google.maps.LatLng(47.3732589, 8.2382168), title: 'x', map:map});  
    marker.show;  
};
</script></head>  
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">  
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>  
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(47.3732589, 8.2382168));
marker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 4):

You were close, but you forgot the `new` keyword when adding your `position`. It should look like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.3732589, 8.2382168), title: 'x', map:map});
```